# Partial string matching between two columns in R

Tags: r, string-matching

I'm trying to verify that the emails for a list are correct. I was thinking I could do a partial string match between Email and Name columns, and return a logical vector (TRUE/FALSE) in a new column.

In the example below, only rows 3 and 5 have correct emails, and the output would be 'TRUE' for these rows. I tried the following, and it hasn't worked:

```
>for (i in Test$LastName) {
 Test$Match <- agrepl(i, Test$Email, ignore.case = TRUE)
}

>Test$Email %in% Test$LastName
```

Any other suggestions are welcome too. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: I think the [`grepl`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/grep.html) function could be helpful

Comment: There are some nice answers but I'll just add that the reason your code doesn't give you the expected results is because when you pass `Test$Email` to the `agrepl` function, you're passing ALL the email addresses from your data frame.

Comment: You're the best, Ryan! Yes, the answers made me realize that. Thanks so much for helping me understand it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this? You are almost there, just need to store the TRUE/FALSE in a vector. I used sapply, iterate through the rownames and compare the corresponding columns. In sapply, results are stored in a vector so you can use it as a TRUE/FALSE:

```
test = data.frame(FirstName=c("Audrey","Tammy","Stacey","Judson","Kellie"),
LastName=c("Low","Rose","Lock","Porter","Sims"),
Email=c("T.Rose@gmail.com","A.Low@gmail.com","stacy.lock@gmail.com","beth.mccormick@gmail.com","k.sims@gmail.com"))

matches = sapply(1:nrow(test),function(i)agrepl(test$LastName[i],test$Email[i]))

test[matches,]

  FirstName LastName                Email
3    Stacey     Lock stacy.lock@gmail.com
5    Kellie     Sims     k.sims@gmail.com
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand this! This reminded me that I need to store each output in its own home using [i] :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DF <- data.frame(FirstName = c("Audrey","Tammy","Stacey","Judson","Kellie"),
                 LastName = c("Low","Rose","Lock","Porter","Sims"),
                 Email = c("T.Rose@gmail.com","A.Low@gmail.com","stacy.lock@gmail.com","beth.mccormick@gmail.com","k.sims@gmail.com"))
```

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(isMatch = grepl(LastName, Email, ignore.case = T))
```

Output:

```
  FirstName LastName Email                    isMatch    
  <fct>     <fct>    <fct>                    <lgl>
1 Audrey    Low      T.Rose@gmail.com         FALSE
2 Tammy     Rose     A.Low@gmail.com          FALSE
3 Stacey    Lock     stacy.lock@gmail.com     TRUE 
4 Judson    Porter   beth.mccormick@gmail.com FALSE
5 Kellie    Sims     k.sims@gmail.com         TRUE
```

Comment: Love the simple solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A base R option is to use `grepl` + `mapply`

```
Test <- within(Test, Match <- mapply(grepl,paste(FirstNmae,LastName,sep = "|"),Email,ignore.case = TRUE))
```

such that

```
> Test
  FirstNmae LastName                    Email Match
1    Audrey      Low         T.Rose@gmail.com FALSE
2     Tammy     Rose          A.Low@gmail.com FALSE
3    Stacey     Lock     stacy.lock@gmail.com  TRUE
4    Judson   Porter beth.mccormick@gmail.com FALSE
5    Kellie     Sims         k.sims@gmail.com  TRUE
```

**DATA**

```
Test <- data.frame(FirstNmae = c("Audrey","Tammy","Stacey","Judson","Kellie"),
                 LastName = c("Low","Rose","Lock","Porter","Sims"),
                 Email = c("T.Rose@gmail.com","A.Low@gmail.com","stacy.lock@gmail.com","beth.mccormick@gmail.com","k.sims@gmail.com"))
```